# Blender crashes when opens Shader Editor

Tags: crash, shader, editor, nodes, blender

there!

I haven’t been able to use the Shader Editor. Im using Blender 2.9.1. I have proved different versions and only works in my computer in Blender 2.69.

1- I open Blender 2.9.1 (empty project)
2-I switch to Shader Editor (Shift F3)
3- Blender crashes

This hapens with Cycles, Eevee and Workbench. Any suggestions?

PC info:
Ubuntu 14.04
Intel core i7
7.7 Gb RAM
Intel corporation 3rd Gen Core Graphics Controller (rev 09)

This is the crash log file of Blender:

```
Blender 2.90.1, Commit date: 2020-09-23 06:43, Hash 3e85bb34d0d7

bpy.context.space_data.context = ‘RENDER’ # Property
bpy.context.area.ui_type = ‘ShaderNodeTree’ # Property
backtrace

/snap/blender/47/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x20) [0x81fdd40]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0xe2329d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36cb0) [0x7f6f851e7cb0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2ea2fe) [0x7f6f6785d2fe]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e13f6) [0x7f6f678543f6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e1496) [0x7f6f67854496]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e07c8) [0x7f6f678537c8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e2c25) [0x7f6f67855c25]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e2178) [0x7f6f67855178]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e12ca) [0x7f6f678542ca]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2e076c) [0x7f6f6785376c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2a7b45) [0x7f6f6781ab45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x2eb3fa) [0x7f6f6785e3fa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x423131) [0x7f6f67996131]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x37b1e0) [0x7f6f678ee1e0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x21823e) [0x7f6f6778b23e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x1308ea) [0x7f6f676a38ea]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create_ex+0x687) [0x6f1a7a7]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create+0x12) [0x6f1b032]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_create_from_arrays_impl+0xb7) [0x6f1b0f7]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_shader_get_builtin_shader_with_config+0x1c2) [0x6f1b772]
/snap/blender/47/blender(GPU_batch_program_set_builtin_with_config+0xd) [0x6f03b9d]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0x184275c]
/snap/blender/47/blender(nodelink_batch_end+0x28) [0x1843d98]
/snap/blender/47/blender(node_draw_nodetree+0x11d) [0x184781d]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0x1847967]
/snap/blender/47/blender(drawnodespace+0x449) [0x1847dc9]
/snap/blender/47/blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x811) [0x1487631]
/snap/blender/47/blender(wm_draw_update+0x4da) [0x10deb5a]
/snap/blender/47/blender(WM_main+0x30) [0x10dcab0]
/snap/blender/47/blender(main+0x317) [0xd5ec67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f6f851d2f45]
/snap/blender/47/blender() [0xe1fa83]
Python backtrace
```

Comment: You may better ask your question in the Blender Stackexchange page: https://blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just added it in Blender Stackexchange.

Comment: For future readers it would be great if you link them together ;-)